# No such File or Directory in Codeblocks

Tags: c++, mingw, codeblocks

I have been trying to run C++ programs on Codeblocks.
But every time I compile it, it shows me the following error: No such file or directory.

I've tried implementing all the options I could find on Google:

1. I've reinstalled it around 10 times now.
2. I've tried changing Compiler settings and MinGW path.
3. No, I'm not making a C project and then running a C++ program on it.

[Please click here in order to see the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7OqGF.png)

I have gone through so many sites ans so many solutions, but none of them seems to work out for me.
Also, I was happily running Codeblocks for 2-3 years now, when suddenly something happened and I thought of reinstalling it. Ever since, this has been happening to me. Please help!

Comment: You need to copy and paste the full error message if anyone is going to be able to help you.

Comment: I've added a link to the screenshot of the error message.

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow. To get any help you will need to to post the build log of the failing build. You will find it in **Build log** tab (not the **Build messages** tab) of the failing Codeblocks build. Posting links to offsite pictures is not an acceptable way of providing build information on SO.